# How can I add items from a alertDialog to a list?

Tags: flutter

I have a alert Dialog with a dropdown and textfields and I want to add that information to a list

I tried this but I can't get the expected result, only when I do a hot reload the new data appears on the list.
I added the setState, tried whit the initState and more things but nothing appears to work. I don't know any more options to solve this problem.

I'm working with flutter windows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> servicios = [
    'Monitoreo y control de abejas',
    'Monitoreo y control de arañas',
    'Monitoreo y control de aves',
    'Monitoreo y control de avispas/lechiguanas',
    'Monitoreo y control de coleopteros',
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> serviciosSeleccionados = [];
  String? servicioSeleccionado;
  popUpServicios(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            String? nuevoServicioSeleccionado;
            String desde = '';
            String? hasta = '';
            String? comentario = '';
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Agregar Servicio'),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          items: servicios.map((e) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: e,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
                                  child: Text(
                                    e,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  )),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              nuevoServicioSeleccionado = value;
                            });
                          },
                          value: nuevoServicioSeleccionado,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          desde = value;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          hasta = value;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          comentario = value;
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Cancelar'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (nuevoServicioSeleccionado != null &&
                            desde.isNotEmpty) {
                          setState(() {
                            serviciosSeleccionados.add({
                              'servicio': nuevoServicioSeleccionado!,
                              'desde': int.parse(desde),
                              'hasta': int.parse(hasta!),
                              'comentario': comentario,
                            });
                            servicioSeleccionado = nuevoServicioSeleccionado;
                          });
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text('Agregar'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Servicios',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                popUpServicios(context)
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 500,
              width: 300,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: serviciosSeleccionados.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  final servicio = serviciosSeleccionados[i]['servicio'];
                  return Dismissible(
                      key: Key(servicio),
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
                        return await showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              title: const Text("Confirmar"),
                              content: const Text(
                                  "¿Estas seguro de querer borrar el servicio?"),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () =>
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                                  child: const Text("CANCELAR"),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                                    child: const Text("BORRAR")),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        setState(() {
                          serviciosSeleccionados.removeAt(i);
                        });
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text('$servicio borrado'),
                        ));
                      },
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(servicio),
                      ));
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your `StatefulBuilder` is inside the State class, calling `setState` will changes the StatefulBuilder's state.  You can rename one the StatefulBuilder's  `setState` to something else and call it.

like

```dart
return StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateSB) {
    return AlertDialog(
     ....
        setStateSB(() {                             
             serviciosSeleccionados.add({...});
        }); //update dialog ui
       setState((){});//update main ui
```

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> servicios = [
    'Monitoreo y control de abejas',
    'Monitoreo y control de arañas',
    'Monitoreo y control de aves',
    'Monitoreo y control de avispas/lechiguanas',
    'Monitoreo y control de coleopteros',
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> serviciosSeleccionados = [];
  String? servicioSeleccionado;

  Widget popUpServicios(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            String? nuevoServicioSeleccionado;
            String desde = '';
            String? hasta = '';
            String? comentario = '';
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateSB) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  scrollable: true,
                  title: const Text('Agregar Servicio'),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isDense: true,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        items: servicios.map((e) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: e,
                            child: Text(
                              e,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            nuevoServicioSeleccionado = value;
                          });
                        },
                        value: nuevoServicioSeleccionado,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          desde = value;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          hasta = value;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          comentario = value;
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Cancelar'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (nuevoServicioSeleccionado != null &&
                            desde.isNotEmpty) {
                          setStateSB(() {
                            serviciosSeleccionados.add({
                              'servicio': nuevoServicioSeleccionado!,
                              'desde': int.tryParse(desde) ?? 0,
                              'hasta': int.tryParse(hasta ?? "") ?? 0,
                              'comentario': comentario,
                            });
                            servicioSeleccionado = nuevoServicioSeleccionado;
                          });
                          setState(() {});
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text('Agregar'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Servicios',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                popUpServicios(context)
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: serviciosSeleccionados.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    final servicio = serviciosSeleccionados[i]['servicio'];
                    return Dismissible(
                        key: Key(servicio),
                        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                        confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
                          return await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text("Confirmar"),
                                content: const Text(
                                    "¿Estas seguro de querer borrar el servicio?"),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                                    child: const Text("CANCELAR"),
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                                      child: const Text("BORRAR")),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          setState(() {
                            serviciosSeleccionados.removeAt(i);
                          });
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('$servicio borrado'),
                          ));
                        },
                        background: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(servicio),
                        ));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: great  upvoted vai